# Search result pagination, best practice

Tags: web-services, search, pagination

I have some results obtained through WS requests from a couple of different providers, then i gather and order the results and i show them at the user.

The number of the results is somewhere between 0 and 60-70, with an average of 10-20.
My problem is: how to handle pagination? 
 I'm trying to figure out which is the best solution for my situation, because i have find out  several ways to do that... and I am sure I am missing other good (probably better) solutions... The solutions i thought until now:

1)Making for each page (15 results) a new aggregated search through the WebServices. This is stupid, but since the average number of results is 10-20, the pagination wont be used often.

2)Saving in the database all the results as a temporary cache and then showing 15 results at time

3)Loading all the results in a single page but showing only 15 a page using a Jquery pagination plugin (client side?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how big is 1 result, but I'd prefer no pagination if you have max 60-70 results, especially if it's not often. Better user experience.

Comment: i have only 60-70 results, but each result can take from few lines to half-screen so the results page can be very long with more than 10-15 results

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure that someday the web services aren't going to start returning a lot more results? What if someday there is a bug in one of them where it accidentally returns 50,000 copies of the same result to you? In each of your solutions:

1. A larger than expected number of results would cause you to spam the web services with repeated requests for the same results, as users page through them.
2. A larger than expected number of results will end up temporarily taking up space in your database. Also, in a web app, how will you know when to clear the cache?
3. A larger than expected number of results will end up as a huge page in the user's browser, possibly not rendering correctly until the whole thing is downloaded.

I really like option 3. The caching is done at the place where the data is wanted, there are no redundant hits to the web services, and paging will be super fast for the users.

If you're really certain no more than 60-70 results will ever be returned, and/or that your users will never want a really large number of results, you could combine option 3 with a cap on the number of results you will return.

Even in the worst case where the web services return erroneous/unexpected results, you could trim it to the first so many, send them down to the browser, and paginate them there with JavaScript.